# "You OK?" - When can I omit the verb?

Tags: verbs, questions

In (American) movies I have often heard people say

> You OK?
>   You ready?

instead of

> Are you OK?
>   Are you ready?

I doubt this is proper English. Or is it? Is it colloquial only? Is it only American "slang"?

Comment: I stopped watching "Homeland" because they used 'You okay?' about 273 times each episode.

Comment: Never mind the *verb!* We don't even bother with the *pronoun* in SE UK, where *"Alright?"* is a standard "greeting" (meaning *"Hi!"*, rather than *"Are you alright?"*).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In an informal way, it's okay. Also, I observe that such sentences are spoken hurriedly. Also, in speech (especially in movies), they don't bother that much of grammar.

I won't say that as proper English but then, since they are quite common in their tongue, the natives make these sentences acceptable!